# Why was my Blanket L1B visa denied and what can I do about it?

Tags: l1-visa

I have applied for L1 blanket visa and appeared for the interview on 5th July 2017 at U.S. Consulate General Chennai office.

I have cleared the interview and the visa officer said that my visa is approved and gave me two copies of I-129S  with an **approved stamp, and took my passport**.

However, when I collected my passport from VFS Ahmedabad dropbox today, attached to it was a blue sheet of paper that says **'Your Blanket L-1 application is not clearly approvable under section 8 CFR 214.2(l)(ii)(D) and INA 101(a)(15)(L).'**

Since the visa officer returned I-129s with an approved stamp, why wasn't my passport also stamped? Do I need to submit any missing documents, or was there an issue with my application?

Comment: Their wording is vague. Without more specific details on the part of the consulate, we can't be sure if it's nothing, a glitch, or something of substance that you can actually do something about. I think you will have to press them about this.

Comment: @Smash - I have the same situation as you. Can you please share, what was your next step or any further updates on your case? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user370305 I have sent an email to support-india@ustraveldocs.com with all informations, have attached scanned copies of  I129s , passport n blue slip which i have got along with passport,  they will respond you within 60 days. I have got call from us consulate chennai after 1 month that my visa is not approved , the reason is confidential ,  that's it, don't expect anything unless they asked for particular documents with your passport , all the best

Comment: @Smash - Thanks for reply. Its more than 1 month I didn't get any updates from them or call and still my visa status shows "Issued". It seems like we can't do anything on this.

Comment: Per [8 CFR 214.2(l)(5)(ii)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/8/214.2#l_5_ii), a blanket L-1 visa can only be approved if it's "clearly approvable". If not, the blanket L-1 visa would be denied but you can still have your company file form I-129 in order for you to apply for an individual L-1.